# Calculate the inverse of an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the inverse of an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3)$.

For example $a=2-\sqrt3$.

I was considering at first to find a $b= {1 \over a}$ and from the calculation emerge that $b= 2+\sqrt3$.
But is this process right or wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What process? You did not specify what you actually did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a, b\in \Bbb Q$ and $a + b\sqrt3\neq 0$. Expanding fractions gives us
$$
\frac{1}{a + b\sqrt3} = \frac{a - b\sqrt3}{a^2-3b^2}\\
= \frac{a}{a^2-3b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2-3b^2}\sqrt3
$$
Note that $\sqrt3$ being irrational is precisely what we need to see that the denominators aren't $0$.

Comment: So in my example $a=2$ and $b=-1$, so having a $\sqrt3$ factor in the fraction expansion assure us that the inverse is indeed in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$, am I right?

Comment: @Alessar The thing that ensures that the inverse is indeed in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$ is that $\frac{a}{a^2-3b^2}$ and $\frac{b}{a^2-3b^2}$ are rational. I'm expanding by $a-b\sqrt3$ for the simple reason that that makes the denominator rational and much easier to work with.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks for the clarification Arthur